# Cant pass data to template html page [Django]

Tags: python, html, django

I have a python django project where I am simply trying to pass data to a template but, for some reason cannot seem to get it working. My views.py file
is located in myproject/mystuff/views.py and looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("TESTING")

def myview(request):
    tempData = {'firstname': 'bob','lastname': 'jones'}
    weather = "sunny"
    data = {
        'person': tempData,
        'weather': weather
    }
    return render(request,'myproject/templates/myview.html',data)
```

inside the myview.html page I simply have add

```
    <h1>Hi {{ person.firstname }} {{ person.lastname }}</h1>
    <h1>Today it is {{ weather }}</h1>
```

my urls.py located in myproject/mystuff/urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.myview, name='myview'),
]
```

finally, I also have a 2nd urls.py for django rest framework with a urlpatterns[] that holds:

```
url(r'^myview$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='myview.html'), name='home')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure that you're putting your code in the right template files, if you add something else in the template, will that print to the screen? Like if you just put plain text `THIS IS A TEST` or something. Will that actually be displayed for the page you want it to be displayed for?

Comment: And by the way, what version of django do you use?

Comment: @Azer Yes, if I add anything to the html page myview.html, it will be displayed on http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview So, even the text before the variables "Hi" "Today it is" are both displayed, just not passed in data.

Comment: @Azer I am using 2.1.5

Comment: In newer version of Django, including 2.1.5 that you are using, it is adviced to use `path` to build url paths. You import it like this: `from django.urls import path` and then your views `from . import views` and then you can build url patterns like this: `urlpatterns = [path('myview', views.myview, name='myview')]`

Comment: This goes in the urls.py file as you did before. I don't know if that will solve your issue, but you should do it either way as it is the recommended way to build paths. Otherwise I see no reason why your view wouldn't work, but I have never used the rest framework extension for Django, so perhaps it's interfering somehow with the templates?

Comment: @Azer I cant seem to get that working and load my html page now. The main driving thing that loads my html page is the url(r'^myview$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='myview.html'), name='home') in urls.py

Comment: I'm probably just bad at explaining, here's the official tutorial that shows how to build url paths with `path`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/ (scroll down a bit) and here's the reference to `django.urls.path` in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/

Comment: @Azer Got it working with the change to url patterns in your tutorial.

Comment: Great! I'm happy to hear it. I'll add an answer below so others with the same problem will find the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you are passing data is correct.

However, in newer version of Django, including 2.1.5 that you are using, it is adviced to use `path` to build url paths.

You use it like this in urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('myview', views.myview, name='myview')
]
```

Official tutorial that shows how to build url paths with path:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Official documentation for `django.urls.path`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly pass variable into html, you need specify as a dictionary

**Django Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("TESTING")

def myview(request):
    tempData = {'firstname': 'bob','lastname': 'jones'}
    weather = "sunny"
    data = {
        'person': tempData,
        'weather': weather
    }
    return render(request,'myproject/templates/myview.html',{'data':data}) 
#passing value in a dictionary
```

In Html page ,we can access value dictionary key value

```
<h1>Hi {{ data.person.firstname }} {{ person.lastname }}</h1>
<h1>Today it is {{ data.weather }}</h1>
```

Comment: Ok, I added this but, still am not able to see data in webpage. I even tried altering html to look like this, {{ data.person.firstname }} {{ data.person.lastname }} {{ data.weather }}

Comment: There's no need for the additional dictonary in the response. You can just pass the `data` dictonary directly, as it is in the question.

Comment: please wait .. i will definitely help you .. can you explain what is the output?

Comment: when i run the code i got the output `Hi bob
Today it is sunny`

Comment: The output on the html page is simply "Hi     Today it is     "

Comment: please share your views.py after changes.

Comment: Im starting to suspect it has to be some other reason, maybe something with my settings.py file is affecting it...?

Comment: No errors in console output. For whatever reason my views.py is not properly connected to the html page located in templates folder. Thats the only logical reason I can think of which is why I was suspecting either urls.py or settings.py

Comment: oh .. i can help you.. can you share your code in any git repository .